# Adding a child item to nhibernate bag, more queries than necessary

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Suppose I have a parent collection with the next mapping:

```
public class A : Entity<A>
{
    private readonly IList<B> _bs = new List<B>(); 
    public virtual string AProp { get; set; }
    public A(string aprop)
    {
        AProp = aprop;
    }
    protected A()
    {
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<B> Bs
    {
        get { return _bs; }
    }

    public virtual void AddBEntity(B bEntity)
    {
        bEntity.A = this;
        _bs.Add(bEntity);
    }
}

    public class AMap : EntityMap<A>
    {
        public AMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.AProp).Not.Nullable();
            HasMany(x => x.Bs)
                .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
                .Inverse().Cascade.All().AsBag();
        }
    }
```

And the next child class and its mapping:

```
    public class B: Entity<B>
        {
            public virtual string BProp { get; set; }
            public virtual A A { get; set; }
        }

        public class BMap : EntityMap<B>
        {
            public BMap()
            {
                Map(x => x.BProp).Not.Nullable();
                References(x => x.A).Cascade.All();
            }
 }
```

Suppose I need to add children to an existing parent. I would expect one insert in SQL with already known values of the child and the id of the parent in place.
I tried different things with mapping but I do not understand why would I load a proxied A object for adding a child as the NH profiler  suggests I do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you have a list of A proxies and want to add one or more Bs to each A. If this is not true please show us your code where you load/create As and add Bs.

Your A proxies are loaded as soon as you call any public method on it. In your case this is most likely the `AddBEntity` method or the `Bs` property getter. NHibernate can't know what you want to do in that methods and properties and therefore always has to initialize the proxy.

I'm not completely sure right now but I think you can insert new Bs without loading your A proxies by doing something like the following. Basically just make sure you never call a method on the A proxies.

```
B newB = new B();
newB.A = someAProxy;
session.Save(newB);
```

Comment: yes, I tested that out and it helps but there are cases when the domain supposes two-way association and you need to add the link to both ends.

Comment: @Hohhi If you first access the `Bs` collection after saving the new Bs they will be there, so this shouldn't be a problem. You only have to add them to the `Bs` collection yourself if that collection is already loaded before saving the new Bs.

Comment: Yes but if I do not clear the session on flush, I could get the dirty session, could not I?

Comment: @Hohhi Sorry, I don't understand your question. Why would you clear the session after flushing?

Comment: Because if I had A instance attached to session and do not add to both ends, I shall have a dirty A object graph with no B entity which was just added

Comment: @Hohhi Yes, but this can only happen if the A proxy was already loaded before you inserted the B. Your original question states that they were not yet loaded (otherwise adding the Bs wouldn't have caused NHibernate to load them again).